# Issue with selenium getting stuck when trying to press on a browser button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape the website *https://demanda.ree.es/visiona/peninsula/demanda/tablas/2021-03-26/2* with Selenium on Python, through a simple code that has to click an arrow to change the date visualised and then click on a span element which leads to the download of the CSV file. This is repeated 1000 times in order to download 1000 csv files. I have attempted to do so by using the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://demanda.ree.es/visiona/peninsula/demanda/tablas/2021-03-25/2')

for i in range(1000):
    WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='md-icon-button main-menu md-button md-ink-ripple']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='export-csv']"))).click()
driver.close()
```

However, when I try to run the code, it successfully opens the browser and clicks on the arrow, but then gets stuck for some reason and does not manage to click the element that leads to the file download. How could I resolve this issue?

The error that is returned within python is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-c47407eb9220> in <module>
      5 for i in range(2):
      6     WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='md-icon-button main-menu md-button md-ink-ripple']"))).click()
----> 7     WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='export-csv']"))).click()
      8 driver.close()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

The procedure should be as follows:

[Link to example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCk4m.jpg)

Comment: Does it clicks the arrow ? I highly doubt it. Xpath has two matches - https://imgur.com/a/1xukf85

Comment: If you want to click left arrow try this - `//button[@class='md-icon-button main-menu md-button md-ink-ripple'][1]` and for right arrow try this - `//button[@class='md-icon-button main-menu md-button md-ink-ripple'][2]`

Comment: @Madhan actually it does click the arrow and the page changes correctly (probably because it chooses the first one automatically). I tried changing the arrow line to what you suggest and it works correctly also in this way, but still gets stuck when trying to locate and press the second button

Comment: Can you try this xpath for downloading csv `//table[@id='tabla_generacion']//img` ?

Comment: This one works! Amazing, thank you very much!!

Comment: If you found this answer to be correct, please mark it as answered and up vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there was multiple matches of xpath `//span[@class='export-csv']` found couldn't able to click on the element correctly. Exact xpath to download the csv is `//table[@id='tabla_generacion']//img`